# How to add multiple constraint violations for the same property node?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I have a custom `ConstraintValidator`. What i want to do, is to add multiple constraint violations for the same property node, with the same message, and different dynamic payload. Is this possible?

Custom annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomFieldConstraintValidator.class)
public @interface CustomFieldConstraint {
    String message() default "message";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Custom constraint validator:

```
public class CustomFieldConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomFieldConstraint, Integer> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        var valid = true;
        var hibernateConstraintValidatorContext = context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);
        hibernateConstraintValidatorContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();

        if (value > 0) {
            valid = false;

            hibernateConstraintValidatorContext.withDynamicPayload(Map.of("must_be_less_than", 0))
                .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate())
                .addPropertyNode("field")
                .addConstraintViolation();
        }

        if (value > 5) {
            valid = false;

            hibernateConstraintValidatorContext.withDynamicPayload(Map.of("must_be_less_than", 5))
                .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(context.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate())
                .addPropertyNode("field")
                .addConstraintViolation();
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Validator test:

```
public class HibernateValidatorTest {
    private final Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

    @Test
    void multipleFailuresForSameField() {
        var foo = new Foo(10);

        var constraintViolations = validator.validate(foo);

        assertEquals(2, constraintViolations.size());
    }

    public static class Foo {
        @CustomFieldConstraint
        private int field;

        public Foo(int field) {
            this.field = field;
        }
    }
}
```

The test is failing with `expected: <2> but was: <1>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this issue because `ConstraintViolation` are returned as a set and, by design, the dynamic payload is not included in the `equals()` method. See https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/ConstraintViolationImpl.java#L251 .

Thus your 2 constraints are considered equal at the Set level.

You need to change the way you do things and enrich the payload with both information instead.

Comment: Hibernate validator just makes it too hard to handle such simple tasks :(